# How to assign a value of a particular field to another field inside same document in Firestore Swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I have three fields inside a document say `Count`, `Rating` and `AvgRating`. Now I update the document and say I assign some values to `Count` and `Rating`. I also want to update the value of `AvgRating` by getting the values of `Count` and `Rating` and dividing them. Now the problem is how can I get the values of `Count` and `Rating` here?

```
db.collection("ABC").document("XYZ").updateData([
    "Count" : 2,
    "Rating": 13,
    "AvgRating": "//Need help here, want something like value Of Rating / value of Rating"
])
```

Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a document before writing is necessary to get the value which is already present.

You have two options

(1) Either first read the document, then in the closure where you get the snapshot of document, read values, then after calculations, update data of the document inside that closure.

(2) Use transaction to first read the data, then update the data.

I recommend you to use transaction, because it performs the operation in one go. (The first method can also be applied here without any fear of failure)

First, create a document reference like:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let ref = db.collection("ABC").document("XYZ")
```

then,

```
db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in

let document = DocumentSnapshot?
do
{
    document = try transaction.getDocument(ref)
} 
catch
{
    print(error)
    return nil
}
    
guard let data = document.data()
else
{
return nil
}

//you have document data here take the values

let count = data["Count"] as! Int
let rating = data["Rating"] as! Int

//perform the calculations

let average = rating / count

//and finally updating data like

transaction.updateData([
    "Count" : 2, //new count value
    "Rating": 13, //new rating value
    "AvgRating": average //calculated value
])

return nil

}) {
    (object, error) in
     if let error = error
     {
         print(error)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do that atomically, you will have to read the document first, and then apply the transformation as required and write the resulting document.

The Firestore client SDK supports some kind of [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) that let you do just that

Comment: Okay right. I thought there might exist any function to do that type of stuff. Seems like have to stick with reading first and then updating. Thanks